# CentOS 7 ask for cabextract even when is installed

Tags: linux, centos7

I wanted to install msttfonts on CentOS 7. Following [this guide](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/) everything goes fine, until I got to run the command:

```
# rpmbuild -bb msttcorefonts-2.5-1.spec
```

The system then throws this message:

```
cabextract is needed by msttcorefonts-2.0-1.noarch
```

It is pretty obvious that I've to install cabextract, so I did. By Downloading source from [here](http://cabextract.org.uk/), extracting, and then ./config... make... make install... (you know guys: all the routine). And I confirm the installation was successful with

```
# cabextract --version
```

Which answers with

cabextract version 1.6

So, I go back with my command rpmbuild... But the system stills answer me

```
cabextract is needed by msttcorefonts-2.0-1.noarch
```

And now, the questions:

What I'm doing wrong? Do I need to reboot the server? Is there a kind of command to tell the server "hey! this cabextract thing is already installed"?

... and well, while I was writting this question, I could resolve it thanks [to this post](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-microsoft-truetype-fonts-in-centos-6-rhel-6.html). So I just leave this question just for further reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *install the `cabextract` package* (by running `yum install cabextract`).

The message you are seeing is a dependency error: the `msttcorefonts-2.5-1.spec` file lists a dependency on `cabextract`, but because you have installed it from source there is no information about it in the local packages database.

Comment: I suspect something like that. But, there isn't a way to tell the OS a cabextract has already been installed?

Comment: Installing and removing packages is how you manipulate the package database.  If you want to install *some* things from source, then plan on installing *all* things from source.  Trying to mix the two models just leads to confusion.

Comment: If for some reason you cannot install `cabextract` via `yum`, you can always edit the `.spec` file and remove the `cabextract` dependency and then run `rpmbuild`. (see larsks note/caution again about mixing source builds with package management installs -- yes you can do it, but instead of the package management db keeping track of all installs, not part of it is up to you -- keep good notes...)